# Estrange behaviour in JavaScript array clone equality assertion

Tags: javascript, arrays, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I have found a failing assertion in a JavaScript unit test that I would like to fix. The unit test code is the following (the full code can be found [here](https://github.com/remojansen/chai-fuzzy/blob/master/test/chai-fuzzy.js#L318)):

```
    beforeEach(function() {
      arrNeedle = ['waffles'];
      objNeedle = {w: 'waffles'};
      strNeedle = 'waffles';
      numNeedle = 3.14159

      arrDupe = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arrNeedle));
      objDupe = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objNeedle));
      strDupe = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(strNeedle));
      numDupe = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(numNeedle));

      arrContainer = [arrDupe, objDupe, strDupe, numDupe];
      objContainer = {
        arr: arrDupe
        , obj: objDupe
        , str: strDupe
        , num: numDupe
      };

      arrMissing = ['chan'];
      objMissing = {missing: 'chan'}
      strMissing = 'chan';

    });

    it("has its test set up correctly", function() {
      arrNeedle.should.not.equal(arrDupe);
      objNeedle.should.not.equal(objDupe);

      arrContainer.should.not.contain(arrNeedle);
      arrContainer.should.not.contain(objNeedle); // fails

      objContainer.arr.should.not.equal(arrNeedle);
      objContainer.obj.should.not.equal(objNeedle);
    });
```

In the test we are cloning an object and inserting it into an array:

```
objNeedle = {w: 'waffles'}; // original
objDupe = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objNeedle)); // clone
arrContainer = [arrDupe, objDupe, strDupe, numDupe]; // add clone to array
```

The  failing assertion checks that the array (contains the cloned object) doesn't contain the original object.

```
arrContainer.should.not.contain(objNeedle); // fails
```

I tried with an external assertion plugging (chai-things) with no luck:

```
arrContainer.should.not.include(objNeedle); // fails
arrContainer.should.not.include.something.that.deep.equals(objNeedle); // fails
```

The following assertion pass the test but is not the ideal solution:

```
arrContainer[0].should.not.equal(objNeedle); // pass
```

Do you know why is the array considered equal to it's clone only in some cases?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the ChaiJS code, you will see on [line 189 of /lib/chai/core/assertions.js](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/master/lib/chai/core/assertions.js#L189) the following:

```
if (_.type(obj) === 'array' && _.type(val) === 'object') {
  for (var i in obj) {
    if (_.eql(obj[i], val)) {
      expected = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

This is inside the `include(val, msg)` function, which is what is used by the `.contains()` matcher (see [line 215](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/master/lib/chai/core/assertions.js#L215)).

This means that if the `obj` (the thing being tested) is an array and the `val` (the parameter to the `.contains()` matcher function) is an object, as it is in your case, it will check for deep equality using `_.eql()` (`_.eql` is an alias for the function provided/exported by the external `deep-eql` module).